# Docusaurus: Swizzle Navbar - Tweak Navbar items behavior with version change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, navbar, docusaurus

I want to customize my Navbar in such a way that, say when versions 1.2.0 and below are viewed, only Dropdown A should be visible. When versions 1.3.0 and above are viewed, Dropdown B or more must be visible.

#### **For clear understanding:**

**Navbar when browsing version 1.3.0 and above:**

[image]

**Navbar when browsing version 1.2.0 and below:**

[image]

Please let me also know if Wrapping will help or if will I have to Eject. Moreover, it would be great if someone could demonstrate this exact behavior because I am not sure what to import and tweak after swizzling.

I tried to swizzle Navbar and NavbarItem components but not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try working with conditional Rendering on that dropdown**

```
<Greeting isLoggedIn={false} />
```

this link will help you I guess

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I wanted to know what Docusaurus default items I should select for an ideal output. I do not want to change much. But I guess I will need to use Eject swizzle in Docusaurus - that means customizing the Navbar from scratch.